# Jest test passes but error not caught and logs to console

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Is there a way to test custom errors in a component in Jest without there being an Uncaught error thrown in the console?

Here I have a simple button component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {

        if (!this.props.type) {
            throw new Error('Button requires a type prop');
        }

        return (
            <button className={`btn btn-${this.props.type}`}>Button</button>
        );
    }
}
```

When the component is used without providing the type property, I want my custom error to be thrown. I also have the following Jest test:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Button from './button';

it('throws an error if the type prop is not defined', () => {
    const buttonType = undefined;
    const container = document.createElement('div');

    expect(() => {
        ReactDOM.render(<Button type={buttonType} />, container);
    }).toThrow('Button requires a type prop');
});
```

The unit test passes, however the console produces an error similar to:

```
console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
Error: Uncaught [Error: Button requires a type prop]

The above error occurred in the <Button> component:
in Button (at button.spec.js:20)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html to learn more about error boundaries.
```

Usually in Jasmine, the .toThrow() matcher would automatically catch the error and there would be no logging.

I have read about error boundaries, but these seem to be in the application level, not in the component level.

Am I missing an approach that is better suited to test this?

Edit: Using the following versions:

- react: 16.2.0
- react-dom: 16.2.0
- jest: 22.2.2

Comment: Did any of the solution work for you ? I have tried both. Without success.

Answer (score 6):

I have had a similar problem with the virtual-console from jsdom printing the error instead of throwing it. As far as I know, there is no way for Jest or any other testing framework to prevent code from printing to the console.

I have fixed this by replacing the listener that is responsible for printing to the console. The following code is run in a file which is configured in the `setupFiles` in the Jest configuration.

```
// There should be a single listener which simply prints to the 
// console. We will wrap that listener in our own listener.
const listeners = window._virtualConsole.listeners("jsdomError");
const originalListener = listeners && listeners[0];

window._virtualConsole.removeAllListeners("jsdomError");

window._virtualConsole.addListener("jsdomError", (error) => {
  if (error.type !== "not implemented" && originalListener) {
    originalListener(error);
  }
  // swallow
});
```

As you can see, in our case the error that was printed to the console (multiple times, as it was a side effect, and not the main purpose of our test) was a 'not-implemented' error. So it is only those kinds of errors that this code will swallow.

This solution is not ideal, but it will keep the logs cleaner.

PS: If you want to reduce the risk of swallowing 'real' errors, you might be able to use this trick in the `before` method of your test suite and use the `after` method to reset the original behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is indeed React's error handling prevents the error from bubbling up to the top-level, where Jasmine can detect it. Two possible workarounds:

### Monkeypatch console.error to actually throw

```
console.error = msg => { throw new Error(msg); };
```

This is obviously hack and would break if React changed to use a different approach for error reporting. stijndepestel's answer is a more robust approach to this.

### Create an error boundary just for testing

```
let errorInfo = null;
class ErrorBoundary extends React.PureComponent {
    state = {hasError: false};

    componentDidCatch(err, info) {
        errorInfo = [err, info]
        this.setState({hasError: true});
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.hasError)
            return React.Children.only(this.props.children);
        return 'Errored';
    }
}
```

You can then wrap your test in a handler like this one and then assert that `errorInfo` is not null and that it contains an error as you expect